# Why does a bound event activate twice in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-bubbling

I have some HTML:

```
<div class="form-item">
 <a id="listStandardsLink" target="_blank" class="" href="/connect/arisbrowser/standards">Select Standards</a>
</div>
```

And my javascript is:

```
    $("#listStandardsLink").click( function(e) {
        alert("HARD");
        // DO STUFF

        return false;
    });
```

For some reason, I get TWO alerts when I click it. Any ideas?

Comment: probably you have bind somwhere else, or your  code execute twice, code for bind. check that.

Comment: I only get one in Chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/TFTh2/

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/jQfap/ Must be something with the code you didn't post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not sure where else you are binding the click event try to unbind the event before you bind it.

```
$("#listStandardsLink").unbind('click').click( function(e) {
        alert("HARD");
        // DO STUFF

        return false;
    });
```